# C# Save JSON with required formatting using Web.Helpers

Tags: c#, json

I have a system which saves JSON as such:

```
    public static void saveMap()
    {
        string toSave = Json.Encode(Map.Universe);
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(dataDirectory + "Map.json"))
        {
            sw.Write(toSave);
        }
    }
```

Which doesn't currently save in the format I want it to. It currently saves like this:

```
{
"Planets": [{
    "Name": "GY-96547",
    "Location": {
        "x": 0,
        "y": 0,
        "type": "P",
        "galaxyString": "FT-22419"
    }
}],
"Station": {
    "Name": "LT-15743",
    "Location": {
        "x": 0,
        "y": 0,
        "type": "S",
        "galaxyString": "FT-22419"
    }
},
"Name": "FT-22419",
"Location": {
    "x": 0,
    "y": 0,
    "type": "G"
}}
```

I want to save in another way, which my map loading function can understand. I will be able to implement the solution easily, I just need to know it.

Is there a way in Web.Helpers that I can save JSON with formatting that I need, basically - not saving the file "upside down" and also is there a way to save it in a list.

Extra info, just in case you wish to know the format I need to save it in (and currently load it in):

```
{
        "Galaxy": {
            "Name": "FT-22419",
            "Location": {
                "x": 0,
                "y": 0,
                "type": "G"
            },
            "Station": {
                "Name": "LT-15743",
                "Location": {
                    "x": 0,
                    "y": 0,
                    "type": "S",
                    "galaxyString": "FT-22419"
                }
            },
            "Planets": [
                {
                    "Name": "GY-96547",
                    "Location": {
                        "x": 0,
                        "y": 0,
                        "type": "P",
                        "galaxyString": "FT-22419"
                    }
             }
        ]}}
```

Requested definitions:

```
[Serializable]
public class Galaxy
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Planet> Planets = new List<Planet>();
    public Station Station;
    public Location Location { get; set; }

    public Galaxy() { }

    public static string ListContents(Galaxy g)
    {
        int index = Map.Universe.IndexOf(g);
        string ps = "Planets:";
        string st = "|Station:" + Map.Universe[index].Station.Name;

        foreach (Planet p in Map.Universe[index].Planets)
        {
            if (Map.Universe[index].Planets.IndexOf(p) != Map.Universe[index].Planets.Count)
            {
                ps += p.Name + ", ";
            }
            else
            {
                ps += p.Name;
            }

        }

        return (ps + st);
    }
}
```

Map

```
[Serializable]
public class Map
{
    public static List<Galaxy> Universe = new List<Galaxy>(); }
```

Planet

```
 [Serializable]
public class Planet
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Location Location { get; set; }
}
```

and Station is the same as Planet, just renamed.

Comment: What is saved and how is determined by the type being serialized - its not just a formatting thing.

Comment: So how would I add in the fact I want
`{
    "List": [
        {
            "Galaxy": {`

Added in?

Comment: Can you share your class definitions with us? That is probably the issue.

Comment: Added classes..

Comment: Is your map loading function a C# code? Cannot it simply deserialize the JSON?

Comment: Of course it can deserialize the JSON, however it's getting it back into a readable format in my List of Galaxy.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot (and should not) rely on the order of elements in JSON dictonary. According to the spec (http://www.json.org/), they are unordered. For ordering, you need to put things in an array or similar.

For the grouping, you should add the elements that you want grouped together to a list before serialization.

Comment: The ordering does not matter in the JSON file, what does matter is the fact that I want the "Galaxies" to be in an array in the JSON file. A galaxy in my code has a name, a list of planets, single station and a Location. The "Universe" in my code is a list of "galaxies". Everything is in a list, I just need to know how to save it in a list that is a bit more organized, with a header at least.